# Can Eclipse build specific packages in a project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm curious if there's a way to build specific packages in eclipse. For instance, if I have a project with a src folder containing

```
com.example.a
com.example.b
com.example.c
```

Is there a way to build/compile just `com.example.a` and `com.example.c`? I know there's a way to do it in ant, but hopefully there's an eclipse solution too.

Comment: Do you realize that Eclipse automatically builds entire projects by default? Considering that, what is it that you seek to achieve?

Comment: I am working on a project that is shared by a few other people. Currently, their code does not work so I was looking for a way to compile what do know works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude `com.example.b` from the build path.

For different builds/packages/assemblies (jar files?) you should use ant. That's one reason why it is integrated in eclipse.

Comment: This seems to have worked. Thanks! And I will take your advice about using ant.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

- File
- Export...
- Java
- Jar File

There you can select exactly what to build in Eclipse.

For exampe check only `com.example.a` and `com.example.c`.